# CSS dynamic sub-menu is not showing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created dynamic menu in ASP.NET Webform application. Here is the structure of my menu:

[image]

In which sub-menu is properly generated.

Now I am going to apply some CSS to make it eye-catching.

Here is my desire output after applying CSS on it by using SCSS pre-processor.

[image]

**Issue**

The issue on the above image is, the sub-menu abcd is hide behind the abcd2. Which means if I add more 3rd level sub-menu then all sub-menus hide behind the last one.

Here is my dynamic generated HTML which I've copied from browser console.

```
<aside class="ah-master-asidebar">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a class="ah-anchor-tooltip-show" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="/">
                    <strong>Dashboard</strong>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="ah-anchor-tooltip-show" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <strong>Setups</strong>
                </a>
                <ul style="display: block;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Views/NavigationCreation.aspx">
                            <strong>Navigation Creation</strong>
                        </a>
                        <ul style="display: block;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <strong>abcd</strong>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="display: block;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <strong>abcd 2</strong>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Views/SetupFormCreation.aspx">
                            <strong>Form &amp; Navigation Mapping</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Views/RoleCreation.aspx">
                            <strong>Role Creation</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Views/RoleRights.aspx">
                            <strong>Role Rights</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Views/RoleAssignments.aspx">
                            <strong>Role Assignment</strong>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.ah-master-asidebar {
height: auto;
width: 50px;
background-color: #222222;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
margin: 6px;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;

a {
    padding: 6px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .sub-menu {
        width: 160px;
        display: none;

        ul {
            padding-left: 6px;
            width: 160px;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;

            li {
                position: relative;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            li {
                a:hover {
                    background-color: #495057;
                    color: white;
                }
            }

            ul {
                padding-left: 6px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 200px;
            }
        }
    }
}

#menu > li {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 3px 0;

    .sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 6px;
        width: auto;

        li {
            width: 200px;

            a {
                background-color: #222;
            }
        }
    }

    .sub-menu > li:first-child > a {
        background-color: #3276b1;
    }
}

#menu:first-child > li > a.ah-anchor-tooltip-show:hover {
    background-color: #495057;
}
}
```

**JSFiddle**

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/791935/)

**Conclusion**

As I describe my problem briefly, please let me know what I'm doing wrong in my above HTML or CSS code?

Comment: Both abcd and abcd2 are behind the same submenu option which is not logical.

Comment: Found absolutely positioned elements on line 54 of the scss page. :) It seemed to work on the web ide

Comment: @Gerard the sub-menu abcd and abcd2 is sub-menu of parent menu (Navigation Creation). And the issue is that the sub-menu abcd is hide behind the abcd. That's what I mean.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan In that case they should have their own <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change third level html structure to be in one `ul` element, so use this code

```html
<ul style="display: block;">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <strong>abcd</strong>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <strong>abcd 2</strong>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```html
<ul style="display: block;">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <strong>abcd</strong>
    </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <strong>abcd 2</strong>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
showSubmenu();

function showSubmenu() {
  $('#menu li').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().show()
    $('ul .sub-menu > li > ul').stop().show()
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().hide()
    $('ul > .sub-menu > li > ul').stop().hide()
  });
}
```

```css
.ah-master-asidebar {
    height: auto;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #222222;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 6px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    a {
        padding: 6px;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #menu {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        .sub-menu {
            width: 160px;
            display: none;
            ul {
                padding-left: 6px;
                width: 160px;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                li {
                    position: relative;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                }
                li {
                    a:hover {
                        background-color: #495057;
                        color: white;
                    }
                }
                ul {
                    padding-left: 6px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 200px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #menu > li {
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 3px 0;
        .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50px;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 6px;
            width: auto;
            li {
                width: 200px;
                a {
                    background-color: #222;
                }
            }
        }
        .sub-menu > li:first-child > a {
            background-color: #3276b1;
        }
    }
    #menu:first-child > li > a.ah-anchor-tooltip-show:hover {
        background-color: #495057;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="ah-master-asidebar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a class="ah-anchor-tooltip-show" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <a href="/">
                        <strong>Dashboard</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="ah-anchor-tooltip-show" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <strong>Setups</strong>
                    </a>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Views/NavigationCreation.aspx">
                                <strong>Navigation Creation</strong>
                            </a>
                            <ul style="display: block;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <strong>abcd</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                          
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <strong>abcd 2</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Views/SetupFormCreation.aspx">
                                <strong>Form &amp; Navigation Mapping</strong>
                                
                            </a>
                            <ul style="display: block;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <strong>abcd</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                          
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <strong>abcd 2</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Views/RoleCreation.aspx">
                                <strong>Role Creation</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Views/RoleRights.aspx">
                                <strong>Role Rights</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Views/RoleAssignments.aspx">
                                <strong>Role Assignment</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly update your fiddle because your code output confuse me http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/793662/

Answer (score 0):

I found the below part was messing with the styling, the elements were absolutely positioned.

-- EDIT --

It's bad practice to blanket a group of elements with the same coordinates while being absolutely positioned. The reason being is that the elements will all collapse onto the single specified position hiding all but the very top one.

A different CSS only solution would be to use flex style for your menus and sub-menus

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
```

---

Although in your case it's odd because of the list elements you use, which already behave in a sort of flexie way.

---

Original Code Answer

```
#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .sub-menu {
        width: 160px;
        display: none;

        ul {
            padding-left: 6px;
            width: 160px;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;

            li {
                position: relative;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            li {
                a:hover {
                    background-color: #495057;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
            /* Edited I changed position to relative and pushed it up a bit */
            ul {
                padding-left: 6px;
                position: relative;
                top: -30px;
                left: 200px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run your code in my provided fiddle example? If you does, then you don't post it here. because without absolute position we cannot show sub-menu beside the parent menu.

Comment: Yeah I ran it on the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenvansant/oys7b4pv/  => fiddle fork I made you. Also, its bad practice to use absolute position without having positioned elements with values.